# Is Rayleigh scattering from spheres symmetrical about the $E$-vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, dipole

I've been trying to establish for a while whether the angular distribution of scattered energy from a small sphere (relative to the wavelength) is azimuthally symmetrical about the $E$-vector of the impinging photon/wave.

People often offer a $\sin^2\theta$ dependence, but I understand that this refers to the angle between the incident $k$-vector (Poynting vector) and the scattered photon in the plane of the $E$-vector and the $k$-vector.

I've checked several sources, but nowhere can I find the angular dependence of scattered energy in both the plane defined by the $E$ an $k$ vector and also the plane defined with the $E$-vector as normal.

In theory this should be pretty easily representable as a 3D shape, i.e. a doughnut (if the scattering intensity is symmetrical about the axis of the E-vector)

Comment: Isn't the $\sin^2 \theta$ the answer to your question? The distribution is axisymmetric around the direction of the incoming wave, not the electric field vector.

Comment: Could you explain why the distribution is axisymmetric around the incoming wave? 

My understanding is that it would polarise the sphere in a direction perpendicular to the wave, which would create a dipole radiating energy in all directions apart from along the axis of the dipole. 

Why would it by symmetrical about the axis of the impinging wave when the symmetry is broken by the E-vector (that, after all, causes the scattering).

I guess I'm unclear how theta is defined...